# Can a flight instructor applicant take CFII as an inital rating and be endorsed for 61.185(a)(2) and (3)?

Tags: flight-training, far-61, logbook-endorsements

I have some questions about CFII endorsement.

1. Is it possible to do CFII as the initial flight instructor rating?
2. If an applicant wants to do CFII initial, could the applicant be trained and be endorsed for both 61.185(a)(2) and 61.185(a)(3)?

Comment: Do you meet the requirements of 61.195 (h)?  When you say *"can we do CFII initial?* Are you talking about yourself as the holder of a CFII and a CFIA? (maybe expanding on your qualifications would help clarify). Thanks

Comment: @757toga Not 100% sure, but I think OP is asking if CFII can be done as the initial flight instructor rating instead of the typical CFI.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann You might be right. It's item #2 that is most confusing to me "*...could we train and give them...*"

Comment: @757toga I think the verbiage there would be better stated as "Could the applicant be trained and endorsed for 61.185(a)(2)&(3)?". I'll edit the question to that and see if that was what OP was trying to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I’m a bit confused about what you are asking. If you’re asking if you can become a CFII without doing all the other CFI details, the answer is no. In practice, you become a CFI first, then a CFII secondly - even though sometimes the training seems to become concurrent.

As a CFII/MEI, I’ve actually had an initial flight instructor candidate whose goal was to become a CFII. As I remember (many years ago), there was absolutely no confusion about her training plan in my mind. I gave her the requisite flight and ground training, intertwining the CFI and CFII curriculums, scheduled her with a Flight Examiner, and she became a CFII. And there was absolutely no pushback on the Examiners’s end, other than a phone call from him from telling me she was well prepared, and impressed by her decision to go straight to CFII.

A good starting point for reference would be 14 CFR 61 Subpart H. It lists all applicable flight and ground requirements for becoming a flight instructor:

https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/part-61/subpart-H

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE, and thanks for sharing your experience with an instructor candidate taking the less common path.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, CFII can be done as the initial flight instructor rating. However, the endorsement for that would be 61.185(a)(1) [FOI] and (3) [Instrument], not (2) [Recreational, private, and commercial certificate training]. 61.185(a)(2) would be done when the CFI rating training is done which actually covers the relevant training.

The best source I have for this being possible besides from personal experience is the PTS (Practical Test Standards) for Flight Instructor Airplane on page 21 on the table that lists "Flight Instructor Certificate and Rating(s) Held". Both IA (Instrument Airplane) and IH (Instrument Helicopter) are listed. This would presume that it is in fact possible to acquire these ratings prior to applying for the CFI certificate.

[image]

Comment: @757toga No, all three regs do not have to be accomplished for an initial CFI certificate (2) or rating (3). The regs themselves say " certificate/rating applicable to the (aircraft [2]) category". What it is saying is that if you are seeking instructor privileges for rec, private, or commercial, you use (a)(2). If you are seeking instructor privileges for instrument rating, then use (a)(3). SO a CFI initial would need (1) and (2), while a CFII initial would need (1) and (3).

Comment: I also have had experience with this situation. When I first started looking around at places to do my CFI at, I asked if it was possible to do CFII initial and they all answered yes. I would still need to go for my CFI in order to be able to do any sort of real teaching though. The main benefit of it is that it splits the FOI portion into the CFII checkride which shortens the CFI checkride. Not all the places would do it, but they said it was an option that had been done before. I didn't go that route though and went for standard CFI initial.